# Why will my expo-av Video not start playing automatically?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-av

I have a Video that I am rendering with expo-av. The video renders fine, however it will not start playing upon first render. I have the `shouldPlay` prop set to true. I have provided a [snack example here](https://snack.expo.dev/zf2LEnDvT) as well as some code below. **If you use the snack example, please set the simulator to web.**

**Why does the video not start playing automatically?**

```
      <Video
        style={{width: 500, height: 300, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
        shouldPlay={true}
        videoStyle={{width: 500, height:300}}
      />
```

Comment: If you visit the URI, you get an Access Denied error - are you getting the video to play at all?

Comment: For me, it shows the first frame of the video. I can link a screenshot if need be.

Comment: Wait.. the snack, run with "web", does play the video?!

Comment: Anytime I change the url, it works for the first time only. I am testing it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the correct reason given by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), we have [Autoplay policy in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) and [Chromium Autoplay](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay).
AutoPlay Policy may vary from browser to browser, but in most cases it atleast requires a user interaction. Also if audio is muted, then there's a high probability of auto play. The article explains the reason why most of the video streaming websites we see today are muted. The video is muted,if browser supports it will be auto played, if it doesn't, then if the user unmutes it, then it automatically plays.

In short, we have to keep the audio muted and place a mute/unmute button on the screen.
The styling is poor in this demo, but it atleast give an idea on how to proceed further.
The code is provided below and there's also [snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@mearaj/solution_76503516).

```
 // App.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Video, ResizeMode } from 'expo-av';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function App() {
    const video = React.useRef(null);
    const playerButton = React.useRef(null);
    const [isMuted, setIsMuted] = useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            alignItems:"center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            height: "100%",
            width:"100%"
        },
        video: {
            height: "380px",
            width: "400px"
        },
        buttons: {
            display:"flex",
            width: "500px",
            flexDirection: "row",
            padding:0,
            margin:0,
            justifyContent: "flex-start",
            marginLeft:"200px"
        },
        spacing: {
          marginRight: "16px",
        }
    });

    useEffect(()=> {

    },[])

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Video
                ref={video}
                style={styles.video}
                source={{
                    uri: 'https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
                }}
                autoPlay
                useNativeControls
                resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
                shouldPlay={true}
                isMuted={isMuted}
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
            />
            <View style={styles.buttons}>
                <Button
                    style={styles.button}
                    ref={playerButton}
                    title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
                    onPress={() =>
                        status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
                    }
                />
                <div style={styles.spacing}/>
                <Button
                    style={styles.button}
                    ref={playerButton}
                    title={isMuted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute'}
                    onPress={() => setIsMuted(!isMuted)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Nice! It works, and without sound. So much nicer when you are at work ;)

Answer (score 2):

The [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/zf2LEnDvT)  is working just fine.

I do see only the first frame when the [autoplay permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) of the browser (chrome or Firefox) blocks audio.

But if both audio and video are allowed, then the video starts playing immediately.